# backgrounds Slideshow, but text scrolling

Tags: css, scroll, background, slideshow

I have a WebSite with a single background image, fixed and responsive. The page and text on it are scrolling as usual.
This is the code I'm using:

```
body {
    background-image: url(background.jpg);
    background-position: center top;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

I would like to change it; **a Slideshow with 3 background-images**, fixed and responsive, with scrolling page and text.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

you can use css3 animations and keyframes to achieve it.

You can use this link to refer
http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/cfimg/#cfimg3